# What is the current best way to connect to remote X server?

Tags: linux, x11, x11vnc

I have a computer that is running Debian, and has Xorg started.

What is the best way to interact with it? Previously I was using x11vnc tool, but it seems to be old, and rather slow. Are there better options?

Comment: I dont know if is the best option but in general I try to use ssh with -X for export the X system so in that way I can see windows on my screen.

Comment: Yeah, but that will not let me see windows that were running there previously.